# Magento 2 - Get all options from a quote item

Tags: quote, quoteitem

I need to get all the configurable items related to an item in the cart. For example, if the cart item is of a size "XL", then I need to get all the other options like "S", "M" and "L" together with their attributes.

I get all the cart items using the following method:

```
$items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
```

And then I try:

```
foreach( $items as $item ) {
  foreach ($item->getOptions() as $option) {
    // Here I need to get the attributes for each option but I'm not sure how to go about that
  }
}
```

Is `getOptions()` the way to go?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Options depends on product type:

```
switch ($item->getProductType()) {
    case 'configurable':
        $block   = $this->objectManager
            ->get('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Configurable');
        $block->setItem($item);
        $options = $block->getOptionList();
        break;
    case 'bundle':
        $block   = $this->objectManager
            ->get('Magento\Bundle\Block\Checkout\Cart\Item\Renderer');
        $block->setItem($item);
        $options = $block->getOptionList();
        break;
    .....
```